# Angular 2 How to remove a list item from Storage

Tags: windows, angular, typescript, ionic2, storage

How to remove items from the storage (Storage) by clicking on the button. Elements are entered through the input and added to the page. New items are stored in the Storage. Now the situation is this - the elements are deleted on the page by clicking on the button, when I update the page, they still remain in place. They continue somewhere to be stored.

file home.html

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let place of places ; let i  = index" 
  (click)="onOpenPlace(place)">{{ place.title }}
</ion-item>
  <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="deletePlace(i)">Delete</button>
</ion-list>
```

file home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';          /*** does not work ***/

import { ModalController, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NewPlacePage } from "../new-place/new-place";
import { PlacePage } from "../place/place";
import { PlacesService } from "../../services/places.service";
import { Place } from "../../model/place.model";

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
 export class HomePage {
  places: {title: string}[] = [];

  constructor(
    private storage: Storage,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private placesService: PlacesService,
    private modalCtrl: ModalController) {

   }

    ionViewWillEnter() {
      this.placesService.getPlaces()
        .then(
      (places) => this.places = places
    );
   }

    onLoadNewPlace() {
      this.navCtrl.push(NewPlacePage);
   }

    onOpenPlace(place: Place) {
      this.modalCtrl.create(PlacePage, place).present();
   }

    deletePlace(i){                               /*** does not work ***/
      console.log('delete') 
        this.places.splice(i, 1);
   }
}
```

file  places.service.ts

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';          /*** does not work ***/
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Place } from '../model/place.model';

@Injectable()
   export class PlacesService {
     private places: Place[] = [];

   constructor ( private storage: Storage) {}

   addPlace(place: Place) {
     this.places.push(place);
     this.storage.set('places', this.places);
}

   deletePlace(place: Place){                 /*** does not work ***/
     this.storage.remove('places');
}

   getPlaces() {
     return  this.storage.get('places')
       .then(
     (places) => {
       this.places = places == null ? [] : places;
       return this.places.slice();
      }
    );
   }
 }
```

Comment: In your PlacesService, add a method setPlaces(arr:Array<Place>).. In your controller in the deletePlace(i) once you do the splice call setPlaces with your service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your `deletePlace(i)` method, you're removing the item from your *in memory* array of places, but you're not updating the storage.

The `deletePlace(...)` method from your service won't work because you're saving the places in the storage as an array, so you can't remove a specific place.

```
deletePlace(place: Place) {
    this.storage.remove('places');
}
```

---

I would fix it like this:

In your service, create a new method in order to update the storage with the changes you make to the in memory array:

```
saveChanges(places: Array<Place>) {
     this.places = places;
     this.storage.set('places', this.places);
}
```

And then in your component code, call that method after removing a place:

```
deletePlace(i) {
    console.log('delete');

    // Delete the place from the in memory array
    this.places.splice(i, 1);

    // Update the storage with the new list of places
    this.placesService.saveChanges(this.places);
```

}

Comment: Thank you! it works. I still had to change for this
//places: {title: string}[] = [];
  private places: Place[] = [];

Comment: You're absolutely right. Glad to see you make it work :)